# Some help needed with pseudocode in LaTeX

Tags: algorithmic, pseudocode

Hello trying to writte pseudocode in Latex

I cant fix mistake in line 8

code:

```
\begin{algorithm} \caption{Učící mechanismus všech obcí}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While {Obce ještě nedokonvergovaly}
\State t=t+1
\ForEach {KNIES_p $\in$ Population}
\For{$X_i$ $\in$ Zařazené body}
\State KNIES_p.\quad \textbf{Learn}($X_i$, $\beta_t = \frac{t\beta_T}{T}$)
\EndFor
\If{KNIES_p {$\qaq$} KNIES}
\State KNIES(t) = KNIES_p
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please turn your code fragment into a compilabe [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages. Please also explain the connection to `biblatex` as you used this tag.

Comment: Please do not shout on us (Change chapital letters in title of question)! How is this related to your last question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479937/pseudocode-in-latex-with-multiple-for-cycles ? Which error do you get and please make your code snippet compilable ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *many* errors, mostly due to improper treatment of math symbols.

There is no predefined `\ForEach` block, you have to define it yourself.

Supply a definition for `\qaq`, that's not a standard command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\algblockx{ForEach}{EndForEach}{\textbf{foreach} }{\textbf{end foreach}}
\newcommand{\ivar}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\textrm{#1}}

\newcommand{\qaq}{???} % what's this?

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm} \caption{Učící mechanismus všech obcí}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While {Obce ještě nedokonvergovaly}
  \State $t=t+1$
  \ForEach {$\ivar{KNIES}_p \in \tvar{Population}$}
    \For{$X_i\in\tvar{Zařazené body}$}
      \State $\ivar{KNIES}_p$.\quad
             \textbf{Learn}($X_i$, $\beta_t = \frac{t\beta_T}{T}$)
    \EndFor
  \EndForEach
  \If{$\ivar{KNIES}_p \qaq \ivar{KNIES}$}
    \State $\ivar{KNIES}(t) = \ivar{KNIES}_p$
  \EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]